# ORA-4061 but no changes

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Oracle 19c (19.20.0.0.0) on HP-UX

We have a table which has a `COMPOUND` trigger as follows (I am typing this as I cannot copy/paste from work, so forgive any typos):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER the_trigger
   FOR INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON the_table
   COMPOUND TRIGGER

   TYPE table_type IS TABLE OF the_table%ROWTYPE INDEX BY SIMPLE_INTEGER;

   the_type   table_type;
   g_idx      SIMPLE_INTEGER := 0;

   BEFORE STATEMENT IS
   BEGIN
      DBMS_SESSION.RESET_PACKAGE();
   END BEFORE STATEMENT;

   BEFORE EACH ROW IS
   BEGIN
      g_idx := g_idx + 1;
      the_type(g_idx).col1 := :new.col1;
   END BEFORE EACH ROW;

   AFTER STATEMENT IS
   BEGIN
      WHILE g_idx > 0 LOOP
         the_package.the_proc ( the_type(g_idx) );
         g_idx := g_idx - 1;
      END LOOP;
   END AFTER STATEMENT;

END;
/
```

When I run a `INSERT` I get the error:

`ORA-4061: existing state of THE_TRIGGER has been invalidated`

The package/procedure `the_package.the_proc` is valid.

I have another table with basically the same trigger which works perfectly.

The cause is around the `BEFORE STATEMENT`, so taking that out removes the issue. What is puzzling is the other trigger on the other table works .

```
   BEFORE STATEMENT IS
   BEGIN
      DBMS_SESSION.RESET_PACKAGE();
   END BEFORE STATEMENT;
```

Comment: Why do you think that the package needs to call `DBMS_SESSION.RESET_PACKAGE()`?

Comment: Take it from me it needs it to fulfil some other requirement. The approach works in other similar triggers.

Comment: what do you see if you run `select * from all_errors;`?

Comment: The trigger and some test statements work for me on 19c on Windows. Troubleshooting this weird behavior might require a 100% reproducible test case, with table, data, and statements.